# GridView Thumbnails refreshed when scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-gridview, universal-image-loader

In my Android app I´m using Universal Image Loader library for showing photos from the SD card in the GridView. I also set cacheInMemory(true) (like here: [UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/wiki/Useful-Info)).

For showing the pictures I´m using ArrayAdapter with ViewHolder pattern.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    File item = data.get(position);

    if (row == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        row = mInflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, null);

        holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.picture);

        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    if (item.isFile()) {
      String uri = Uri.fromFile(f).toString();
      String decodedUri = Uri.decode(uri);

      Globals.ImageLoader.displayImage(decodedUri, holder.image);
    }

    return row;
}
```

When scrolling through the library, thumbnails are refreshing every time you scroll past them, and refreshing when scrolling past them again. And it´s not very comfortable for user. I want save the images to the memory and load them quickly.

Is it possible?

Comment: Try to use : https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some others params to the UIL:

.imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)

.bitmapConfig(Config.RGB_565)

and

.memoryCacheSizePercentage(50)

From [config](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/wiki/Useful-Info) and it´s look ok.